# Code analysis tool for .NET that doesn't rely on Unit Tests?

Tags: .net, jenkins, code-analysis

I'm looking for a .NET code analysis tool which meets the following requirements:

1. Does not rely solely on Unit Tests to evaluate coverage
2. Open source
3. Jenkins support

I know that FxCop is a popular choice for .NET, but it appears that has now been moved to the premium versions of Visual Studio, and I was hoping to evaluate the open source options.

Thank you

Comment: So you want code coverage or not? And how do you want coverage data to come from?

Comment: Not test coverage, but actual analysis of the code

Comment: without execution of the code, what kind of "coverage" do you want? Actual analysis of the code? Do you mean static analysis? There is no such thing called " analysis coverage".